# Add a single module to Python's import search path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-import, pythonpath

If I set `PYTHONPATH` to some path `/path/to/modules/`, then the path is appended to `sys.path` and I can import modules/packages contained in `/path/to/modules/`.

However, if I only want access to a single module/package, then adding `/path/to/modules/mymod.py` or `/path/to/modules/mypackage/` to `sys.path` does not work.

So is there a way to add only a single module/package to the import search path, rather than adding the entire parent directory?

I am asking because I need to import a single package installed under `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` from within a virtual environment, and I would prefer not to give the virtual environment access to all of the modules/packages installed under that path. (The package has a complicated build process and cannot be easily installed to a virtual environment.)

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/ but I am wondering if it's possible to actually include the package in the import search path, so that the package (and the modules it contains) can be imported normally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way. If you want to import a module you have to add its
parent directory to `sys.path`. But you can remove it later:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/')
import mypackage
del sys.path[-1]
```